# SOA Composite not pulling data from query, dealing with latency

Tags: oracle11g, soa

We have an Oracle SOA Composite that is deployed on Weblogic 11g.  There is a trigger in a mySQL database that kicks off the composite.  When it runs with a new entry the account name is not being populated so I added an additional query for the account name.  I have included a screenshot of the check I have to query account name.

[image]

It appears the corresponding table is not getting updated as fast as the table that the trigger is on.  I tried putting a wait in the composite and that didn't work.  I also tried a wait with a while loop, which hung the composite.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to handle a situation like this?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually an issue with the composite assignments were incorrect and the query did not return any data.